# How can I use my global variable inside an Adapter class? Android

Tags: java, android, adapter, expandablelistadapter

Hi i'm trying to pass a value by using `Global Variable`. I have created a class file where it is extended to `Application` and then add it on my `Manifest`.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {}
```

After that I had created an `Adapter Class` which is extended to `BaseExpandableListAdapter`, I've search on how to set and get the global variable i've created and found this

```
((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).setMy_id(my_id);
```

and to be able to get the value I use this

```
Integer my_id = ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getMy_id();
```

In my `Fragments`, I can use my `getMy_id()` method but when putting it inside the `BaseExpandableListAdapter`, I'm having an error in getActivity(). I already tried using `this` but still it says `Cannot resolve method getApplication()`, is there any other way to get the value of my global variable.

I'm doing this because I'm trying to use `Cursor` for my `ListView`. I wanted to create a `Expandable ListView` where the data is from my database and my `Cursor` have a parameter for it's `WHERE` condition where my data in my global variable will be used.

The reason why I'm using it as a global variable because I use this data in different `Fragments` where it is not static it changes its value depends on the selected item.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post some code and explain exactly what you are trying to do. I didn't quite understand it. I could be wrong since I don't know what you are trying to get here and why, but it seems like it's not the best practice.

Comment: If its a global variable why not make it static and make a direct reference to it. I must be missing something?

Comment: i can't make it static because the id changes whenever you click from the listview and will go to another listview which the id of the selected item will be pass to another listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a constructor in your class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter. The defined constructor should receive a parameters of Context type. Here is the example -

```
private Context mContext;

public YourExpandableListAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    Integer my_id = ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext()()).getMy_id();
}
```

Now create an instance like this in your activity  -

```
YourExpandableListAdapter ob = new YourExpandableListAdapter(this);
```

This should work.

Comment: can i use this inside a fragment?

Comment: In your fragment you don't need Context instance as your fragment has a function called getActivity() so might just use that.

Comment: one more question, instead putting YourExpandableListAdapter ob = new YourExpandableListAdapter(this); in activity can i put it on my fragment ?

Comment: Yes you can but then you need to change the code to this - YourExpandableListAdapter ob = new YourExpandableListAdapter(getActivity());

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve but whatever it is you're doing seems hacky to me! As per answering your question, `getApplication()` needs a context, so when you do

```
((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication())
```

You are essentially using the activitiy's(getActivity()) context. And you cannot call `getActivity()` in an `Adapter` class. Try passing the context of your activity from the activity to the adapter in your constructor, something like.

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this); //This line will be in your activity, and this will be the instance of your activity
```

And your adapter constructor would look something like

```
public MyAdapter(Context context){
    //Use this context to get the application instance, something like
    Integer my_id = ((MyApplication) context.getApplication()).getMy_id();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I'm trying to pass my_id to my adapter class because in my adapter class i'm trying to create a query there that will be use to populate my expandable listview. I tried what have you suggested to do but I'm still having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For Me, all above didn't work. try this:

```
((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getMy_id();
```